# SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 17 - Unable to connect to sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am using windows authentication to connect and below error message is displayed.

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>   ------------------------------
>
> Cannot connect to DESKTOP-7I87M3E\MSSQLEXPRESS16.
>
> ------------------------------
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1) ".

[image: Error Description]

Comment: go to configuration manager and Check Whether SQL Browser is running or not

Comment: SQL Browser is not running

Comment: Run The Browser in Services And Make the Startup To Automatically

Comment: Sajid Ansari Welcome Bro

Answer (score 1):

Run The Browser in Services And Make the Startup To Automatically

Answer (score 1):

Had to go in to SQL configuration manager on my server, locate SQL Server Services and then Server Browser within that selection and restart Server Browser (it was already running and set to automatic by the way) and then I was able to refresh in Visual Studio 2017 on my remote workstation (running Windows 7) and it connected to database on server ok. Without this I had to restart my workstation which meant shutting down a ton of stuff, etc....